# Animating HTML canvas elements

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, setinterval

I am trying to animate elements on the `<canvas>` but setTimeout and setInterval are giving me problems. My data is in an Array. I get its length. For each node I generate an X and a Y, a cardinal direction and a color. Then my drawing function draws a circle for each one of those nodes.

My problems arise when I try and loop with a setInterval. My thinking was that I could establish all the X, Y values, then loop back and increment them each 10ms-100ms. But every time I use setInterval my child Arrays that hold the data for each circle get a length of 3 and the values are set to undefined.

I coded this once using various objects but couldn't get the animation to work. I learned about the issues with scoping setInterval() in objects. I recoded it without establishing a bunch of objects. still no luck.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getTweets();
});

CTX = $('#tweets')[0].getContext("2d");
WIDTH = $('#tweets').width();
HEIGHT = $('#tweets').height();
RADIUS = 10;
TWEETS = [];
CORDS = [];
DIRECTION = ['north','east','south','west'];

function getTweets(){
    $.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=scion&rpp=100",
    function(r){
        var numberOfTweets = r.results.length;
        while(numberOfTweets--){
            TWEETS.push(r.results[numberOfTweets].text);
        }
        plotXY();
        animateTweets()
    });
}

function animateTweets(){
    return setTimeout(plotXY(true),100);
}

function plotXY(animating){
    if(!animating){
        var numberOfTweets = TWEETS.length;
        while(numberOfTweets--){
            var topY = Math.ceil(Math.random()*(HEIGHT-20)),
                leftX = Math.ceil(Math.random()*(WIDTH-20)),
                cardinal = Math.floor(Math.random()*4),
                color = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);

            var valCords = validateCords(leftX, topY);
            CORDS.push([valCords[0], valCords[1], cardinal, color]);
        }
        // console.log('animating false');
        // console.log(CORDS);
    }
    else{
        var numberOfTweets = TWEETS.length;
        while(numberOfTweets--){
            if(CORDS[numberOfTweets][2]=='north'){ //NORTH
                CORDS[numberOfTweets][1]+=2;
                CORDS[numberOfTweets][0]+=2;
            }
            if(CORDS[numberOfTweets][2]=='east'){ //EAST
                CORDS[numberOfTweets][1]+=2;
                CORDS[numberOfTweets][0]-=2;
            }
            if(CORDS[numberOfTweets][2]=='south'){ //SOUTH
                CORDS[numberOfTweets][1]-=2;
                CORDS[numberOfTweets][0]-=2;
            }
            if(CORDS[numberOfTweets][2]=='west'){ //WEST
                CORDS[numberOfTweets][1]-=2;
                CORDS[numberOfTweets][0]+=2;
            }

            var valCords = validateCords(leftX, topY, numberOfTweets);

            CORDS.push([valCords[0],valCords[1],cardinal]);
            CORDS.shift();          
        }
        // console.log('animating true');
        // console.log(CORDS);
    }
    drawCircles();
}


function drawCircles(){
    console.log('drawing');
    var numOfCords = CORDS.length;
    clear();

    while(numOfCords--){
        CTX.fillStyle = CORDS[numOfCords][3];
        CTX.beginPath();
        CTX.arc(CORDS[numOfCords][0], CORDS[numOfCords][1], RADIUS, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
        CTX.closePath();
        CTX.fill();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you storing the array in a persistent place like the window object?

Comment: Well this is a problem: `setTimeout(plotXY(true),100);` - that calls `plotXY(true)` and then passes the result to `setTimeout`. What you need to do is pass a reference to a function, and the simplest way to do that is like this: `setTimeout(function(){plotXY(true);}, 100);` (same applies for `setInterval()`. You probably want to call `setTimeout()` again for the end of your `plotXY()` function, or use `setInterval()`, otherwise your animation will only have one step. (Note: if your function didn't have any parameters you could pass it directly like this: `setTimeout(plotXY,100)`.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks for pointing out my formatting error. I had setInterval but replaced it with setTimeout to see if it was just an issue with timing functions. Which i think it is based on your advice. I've got to make a fe changes now but i think it may have solved my problem.

Comment: In that case I shall add my comment as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the only problem in your code, but one significant problem is the way you are using `setTimeout()`:

```
setTimeout(plotXY(true), 100); // doesn't work
```

That says to call the `plotXY()` function and then pass whatever it returns as the first parameter to `setTimeout`.

Instead, the first parameter to `setTimeout()` should be a function expression or reference to a function like this:

```
setTimeout(plotXY, 100);      // works, but doesn't pass parameter to plotXY()
```

Note that `plotXY` does *not* have parentheses for this purpose. But of course that leaves you with another problem: you want `plotXY()` to be called with the parameter `true`. That is easily solved by wrapping the call to `plotXY()` in another function and passing that other function to `setTimeout()`:

```
setTimeout(function(){ plotXY(true); }, 100);     // works
```

That creates an anonymous function and passes that function to `setTimeout()`.

You probably want to call `setTimeout()` again at the end of your `plotXY()` function, or use `setInterval()`, otherwise your animation will only have one step. Or you can do something like the following, which shows both another way to solve the parameter passing problem and a way to keep calling the function with `setTimeout()`:

```
function plotXYProxy() {
   plotXY(true);
   setTimeout(plotXYProxy, 100);
}
plotXYProxy();
```

Of course you can add some conditional processing within `plotXYProxy()` to decide whether to set each timeout, e.g., you could have `plotXY()` return a boolean as to whether the animation has finished and call `setTimeout()` or not based on that boolean. Or whatever suits.

Everything I just said about the parameters of `setTimeout()` also applies to `setInterval()`.